# trying to import a file of python (where I have the functions) into my main python file

Tags: python, tkinter

hello as i said in my question i am trying to import a file of python (where I have the functions) into my main python file, the file imports however, it gives me an error saying "accounts" is not defined (which is a list I made). I assume this happens because the main file has it defined, but the function file doesn't?, same  thing happens when i try to get the user's input with .get() (  .get() is used in the function file whereas the actual entry box is in the main file so it says `AttributeError: 'final_cart' object has no attribute 'email'`)
(final cart is a class). how can i fix these errors and run the code, without trying to for example defining the list in the "functioon" file (because I have already defined them in the main file).

**here is some of the main code from my main file**

```
import functioon




class Goode_brothers:


    def __init__(self, parent):

   
       self.my_frame = Frame(parent)
       self.my_frame.pack()

   
       self.background = Image.open('images\\food.jpg')
       self.background_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.background)
       self.img = Label(parent, image = self.background_image)
       self.img.place(x = -26, y =0)

    
       self.img_login = PhotoImage(file = 'new-dip-project\\button (3).png')
       self.login_button = Button(parent,image = self.img_login, command = functioon.read_info(self), bd = BORDER, cursor = CURSOR, bg = '#3b353b', activebackground = '#3b353b')
       self.login_button.place(x = 275, y = 340)



    def create_pass(self):

    
       self.password_length = Label(self.root2, text = '')
       self.password_length.place(x = 80, y = 140)

    
       self.pass_word = str(self.password2.get())

    
       if len(self.pass_word) >= 8:
           functioon.save_info(self)
           self.registered = Label(self.root2, text = 'You have successfully registered, this window will now automatically close', font=("open sans", "8"))
           self.registered.place(x = 80, y = 140)
       
           self.root2.after(1500, self.root2.destroy)
       else:
        
           self.password_length.configure(text="""Your password must be atleast eight characters long. Please try again""", font=("open sans", "8"))
```

**code from functions file**

```
from tkinter import*
from PIL import Image, ImageTk


  
def save_info(self):

   
    self.email_reg = str(self.email2.get())
    self.pass_word = str(self.password2.get())
    print(self.email2)
    
    file = open('emails.txt', 'a+')
    ## writing the user credentials first email and the password, seprerating with a comma
    file.write(self.email_reg + ', ' + self.pass_word + '\n')


    
def read_info(self):

    
    with open("emails.txt") as read_ep:
        for line in read_ep:
            
            accounts.append(line.strip().split(", "))
    
    credential = [self.email.get(), self.password.get()]
    
    if credential in accounts:
        self.open_menu()
    else:
        
        self.ep_notexist = Label(root, text = "Your Email or Password is incorrect, Please try again", font=("open sans", "8"))
        self.ep_notexist.place(x = 210, y = 300)
        self.ep_notexist.after(4000, self.ep_notexist.destroy)
        self.email.delete(0, END)
        self.password.delete(0, END)
```

Comment: What is your question? Because the only poorly defined question I see is "why is the accounts variable not recognized in the functions file" and you've answered it yourself already. If you need the variable, defined in main, in another function, pass it along.

Comment: trying to run the functions from the "functioon" file in the main file but i get the error which is described in my question, how can i fix these errors and run the code, without trying to for example defining the list in the "functioon" file (becasue i have already defined them in the main file). sorry I wasn't clear on my question

Comment: Your indentation is clearly wrong; please [edit] to fix it. On the desktop version of this site, you can get code marked up for you by pasting your code, selecting the pasted block, and typing ctrl-K.

Comment: [Example 4: No Definition](https://realpython.com/python-namespaces-scope/#variable-scope)

Answer (score 1):

To import a python file into your main file:

```
import #(file name)
```

or if you want to import a function from a python file to the main file:

```
from """file name remove the ". """ import #function to import from the file
```

> Please note that the file you are importing from should be in the same
> location as you main file.

Answer (score 0):

Because they are defined in another file, `save_info` & `read_info` are not class methods of the Goode_brothers class.

Instead you are passing the object (self) into `save_info` & `read_info` then referencing email and other attributes that don't exist in the Goode_brothers class.

If you must do it like this, define them first before referencing:

```
class Goode_brothers:

    email = ""

    def __init__(self, parent):
        email = "default"
```

Also I recommend renaming the method argument in functioon from self to something else to avoid confusion.

```
def read_info(goode_brothers_object):
    goode_brothers_object.email = "new email"
```

These functions should really be a part of the `Goode_brothers` class.

There might be other issues as well

Answer (score 0):

To use a variable from the main part of your code in the function defined in functioon.py, you will have to pass the variable to the function, similar to functions within the same file.

```
def read_info(self, accounts):
    etc.
```